# Notification disappears immediately

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

This is the code that runs when the foreground service starts.

```
val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel( CHANNEL_ID,
                                "SC noti", // 채널표시명
                                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
serviceChannel.setShowBadge(false)

val fallChannel = NotificationChannel( FALL_CHANNEL_ID, "SC fall noti", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
val notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build()
fallChannel.enableVibration(true)
fallChannel.setSound(notificationSound, audioAttributes)
fallChannel.setShowBadge(true)

val notification: Notification = Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(getText(R.string.notification_message))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setTicker(getText(R.string.ticker_text))
            .build()

val manager = this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
manager.createNotificationChannel(fallChannel)
startForeground(SC_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
```

And this is the code that is executed when certain conditions are met in my foreground service.

```
(getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).let{ notificationManager ->

    val builder: Notification.Builder = Notification.Builder(this@BLEService, FALL_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("낙상 감지")
        .setContentText("낙상이 감지되었습니다.")//취소 기능 추가해야함
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        .setTicker(getText(R.string.ticker_text))

    notificationManager.notify(SC_FALL_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
}
```

Because of the constraint that the foreground service should always be visible in a "channel", we separated that channel and the notification channel.
serviceChannel will be notified normally (shown while service is running, disappear when service is stopped).
But the fallChannel goes away too quickly when I notify it with notify. 0.1 seconds? It disappears immediately and cannot be checked.
I set the priority to HIGH and now a popup notification pops up and I can check it, but it still shows faster than light in the notification center and then disappears immediately.
It is the same whether you go to the phone desktop or in the lock screen state.
As soon as the notification is posted, it disappears. It seems to be deleted for some unknown reason.
Does anyone know the cause?

+) The "1" mark on the badge displayed at the top right of the app will also disappear as soon as it is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing the same problem as me.
I don't know why, but turning on "Accessibility" of "Allow Notification Access" in Settings solved it.